# Zebra ZPL Code to image conversion in Java

Tags: java, zpl

I have requirement to convert ZPL code to an Image in Java. But I cannot use `Labelary` to do this job as its a licensed one.
Can somebody please help me with the approach.

Comment: Can somebody help me on this. Pls

Comment: some problem here..

Comment: got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ZPL documentation](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) from Zebra for getting started.
But there are several java libraries out there for parsing ZPL code. Pic one the fits your needs best.

Comment: Could you shared the Java libraries and document how to use them? I'd appreciate it, and your answer would be complete.

Comment: Sorry, software recommendations are not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the Zebra SDK for Java [SDK LINK-OS](https://www.zebra.com/la/es/support-downloads/printer-software/link-os-multiplatform-sdk.html). Once the library is imported into the project along with the DLL files, you can use this code:

```
public static String generateZPLCode(String imageFilePath, int newWidth, int newHeight, String x_coordinate, String y_coordinate) throws IOException, ZebraIllegalArgumentException {
    // Load the image
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFilePath));
    image = resize(image, newWidth, newHeight);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

    byte[] grfBytes = PngToGrfConverterDesktop.pngToGrf(in);

    String hexData = Hex.encodeHexString(grfBytes);
    int totalBytes = grfBytes.length;
    int bytesPerRow = totalBytes / image.getHeight();

    StringBuilder zplCommand = new StringBuilder();

    zplCommand.append("^F");
    zplCommand.append(x_coordinate);
    zplCommand.append(",");
    zplCommand.append(y_coordinate);
    String comand_image = "^GFA," + totalBytes + "," + totalBytes + "," + bytesPerRow + "," + hexData;
    zplCommand.append(comand_image);

    return zplCommand.toString();
}

private static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, img.getType());
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale((double) newWidth / img.getWidth(), (double) newHeight / img.getHeight());
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    resized = scaleOp.filter(img, resized);

    return resized;
}
```

But also make sure to import the library.

```
import com.zebra.sdk.graphics.internal.PngToGrfConverterDesktop;
import com.zebra.sdk.device.ZebraIllegalArgumentException;
```

With this, you will have a result that you can test on this [URL](https://labelary.com/viewer.html) by placing the code between

```
^XA
 {code_return_function}
^XZ
```