# How to convert from BASE64 to ZPL code (Zebra Print)?

Tags: java, zpl

Good evening, does anyone have an idea how to convert ZPL (Zebra Print) code to Base64 in JAVA ...
Since I want to convert it to Image, but I only find the how to convert from base64 to ZPL.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZPL Code to Image conversion in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606617/zpl-code-to-image-conversion-in-java)